# Is there any difference between Chrome and Firefox and browsers in how they parse strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have a var `fecha` with a string value less take as a example `20130926`. I'm parsing the values to get a valid date object as follow and transform using Moment.js library:

```
fecha = "20130926";
console.log(fecha);
parsed_date = moment(fecha.substring(6,8) + "/" + fecha.substring(4,6) + "/" + fecha.substring(0,4)).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
console.log(parsed_date);
```

In Firefox this works perfectly but in Chrome I get:

> NaN-NaN-0NaN

and I'm lost, what I'm doing wrong? Your can test live [here](http://reynierpm.com/podcast/index.html?id=-317498614)

Comment: what do you get if you log that without the format("DD-MM-YYYY")?

Comment: @JonasGrumann "NaN-NaN-0NaN"

Comment: Have you tried using the substr method instead?

Comment: @sbozzie well, tried right now and results is the same **NaN-NaN-0NaN**

Comment: my guess is that it's actually the `moment()` function not working correctly, as strings are being manipulated in the same manner in both browsers but I found out that date functions can differ between browsers if not used in the standards-compliant way

Comment: from moment.js [doc](http://momentjs.com/) `moment("20130926", "YYYYMMDD").format("DD-MM-YYYY")` should work

Comment: What's the `moment` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
moment("20130926", "YYYYMMDD").format("DD-MM-YYYY")
```